# Replace default pop-up window when exception throws on top level in RCP 4 application

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

How can I replace default pop-up window when exception throws on top level in RCP 4 application?

[image: Default error pop-up window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a class implementing `IEventLoopAdvisor` in the application Eclipse Context. This is given all unhandled errors.

Something like:

```java
class EventLoopAdvisor implements IEventLoopAdvisor
{
  @Override
  public void eventLoopIdle(final Display display)
  {
    display.sleep();
  }


  @Override
  public void eventLoopException(final Throwable exception)
  {
    // TODO Your code
  }
}
```

Note: It is extremely important to call `display.sleep` in the `eventLoopIdle` method.

A good place to set this up is the `@PostContextCreate` of your LifeCycle class (if you have one):

```java
@PostContextCreate
public void postContextCreate(final IEclipseContext context)
{
  context.set(IEventLoopAdvisor.class, new EventLoopAdvisor());
}
```

Note: `IEventLoopAdvisor` is an **internal** class so normally I would not advise using it, but this use does seem to be allowed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.